# Swift 3 SwiftyJson get unknown array keys

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Im getting json with a variable array key/name. I need to use this name in the app. I have tried `let keyINeed = json["venue"][0].arrayObject` but i get nil. `"Meeting rooms"` and `"exit"` are the values i need to populate a table but i can't hard code them as they can and will change

```
{  "venue": {
            "name": "Home Office",
            "Meeting rooms": [{
                "name": "1",
                }],
            "exit": [{
                "name": "Back door",
            }]
        }  
}
```

Comment: its because `venue` is not an array its a dictionary

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: you need to get it like `json["venue'']["Meeting rooms"].array` and same for exit

Comment: But "Meeting rooms" is a variable, for other venues it might be "Shopping centre" for example, so what i need to do is get the name for each of 2 arrays like key1 = json[0] and key2 = json[1]

Comment: @user3550256 You want to get value of `name` right?

Comment: No, i want to get and use literals "Meeting rooms" and "exit"
I can't do json["venue'']["Meeting rooms"] because Meeting rooms will change, its variable

Answer (score 11):

ok, so i worked it out for anyone looking to do the same

```
for (key, value) in json["venue"] {

    print("key \(key) value2 \(value)")

}
```

Comment: If you just want all keys then simply `if let dic = json["venue"] as? [String:Any] {  let keys = dic.keys }`

Answer (score 3):

You should use "dictionaryValue":

so now you can do

```
let data = json["venue"].dictionaryValue
print(data.keys)
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this will give you an unordered list.  If order is important, then @user3550256's answer is a better way to go